# ReferenceError while using onclick in codesandbox website

Tags: javascript, codesandbox

I'm writing a Vanilla JS program in codesandbox environment as shown below:

```js
function Game() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td:first-child {
  border-left-width: 0px;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right-width: 0px;
}

table tr:nth-child(1) td {
  border-top-width: 0px;
}

table tr:nth-child(3) td {
  border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tic-Tac-Toe</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <table width="300" height="300" onclick="Game();">
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I execute the above code snippet in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/nrpmlqz23p) then it gives below error:

> ReferenceError Game is not defined

Not sure why the execution environment of codesandbox is unable to detect the `Game` function. If I write the `alert` statement outside the function then it gets called successfully on page load:

```
alert("hi");

function Game() {

}
```

I've linked the external JS and CSS files correctly in the head tag of the HTML page.

Comment: Seems bug to me that function compile is not available in run mode

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the function as a variable attached to the global `window` object. Try defining the function like this:

```
window.Game = function() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

Alternatively, instead of an inline `onclick` event handler try giving the `table` element an id such as `game-table` and then add an event listener:

```
document.querySelector('#game-table').addEventListener('click', Game);
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why code sandbox needs the window prefix, but working locally does not?